# Getting an error with populateCellWithBlock FirebaseUI

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

I'm getting the error:

> Cannot invoke 'populateCellWithBlock' with an argument list of type ((UITableViewCell, NSObject) -> Void)

I have no idea why this is happening. Any advice would be great. Thanks.

```
self.dataSource.populateCellWithBlock { (cell: UITableViewCell, obj: NSObject) -> Void in
        let snap = obj as! FDataSnapshot
        cell.textLabel?.text = snap.value as? String
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now FirebaseUI accepts `AnyObject` as both parameters. You can cast the type inside of the closure.

```
self.dataSource.populateCellWithBlock { (cell: AnyObject, obj: AnyObject) in
  let snap = obj as! FDataSnapshot
  let theCell = cell as! UITableViewCell
  theCell.textLabel?.text = snap.value as? String
}
```

We're working on better Swift compatibility in upcoming releases.

Comment: If you're using XCode 7 beta 5+, with support for `__kindof` then the original should work (though, for reasons lost on me and not clear in the documentation, subclasses of those types don't seem to work, even though they do in Obj-C); otherwise, without `__kindof` support, the type defaults to `id` or `AnyObject` which is why David's solution works. See https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/master/FirebaseUI/XCodeMacros.h#L58-L62 for more info on how this is implemented.